# Contour integral method

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Let $f(z)=z^5-3iz^2+2z-1+i$. Evaluate the integral of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ around a contour $C$ where $C$ encloses all the zeroes of $f$.

I'm not sure what to do here. It seems unlikely I should be expected to find the roots of $f$ so as to use the residue theorem

Comment: The condition is that $C$ shall enclose all zeros of $f$. That's all you need, since then it encloses all poles of $\frac{f'}{f}$. You know what the residue in a zero is, so you can add them up without actually finding any zero.

Comment: @DanielFischer Depends if they are simple poles doesn't it?

Comment: Then perhaps you should attempt to proove that the poles are simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more detailed hint than what I provided in comments, since I just confirmed the direction I had in mind actually works.

Given $z_0$ (some root of $f$ with multiplicity $m$) write $f(z) = (z-z_0)^m g(z)$, for some polynomial $g$ which is nonzero at $z_0$.

This should aid you in first prooving that all the poles of $\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ are simple, then evaluating the limit you will then know is the residue at $z_0$ - happily independent of the actual value of the root.

**Edit**: A large, and hopefully helpful prod in the right direction.

Note that: $$f'(z) = m(z-z_0)^{m-1} g(z)+(z-z_0)^m g'(z) = (z-z_0)^{m-1} (m g(z)+(z-z_0)g'(z))$$

Thus $$\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{(z-z_0)^{m-1} (m g(z)+(z-z_0)g'(z))}{(z-z_0)^m g(z)} = \frac{m g(z)+(z-z_0)g'(z)}{(z-z_0) g(z)} = \frac{m}{z-z_0}+\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$

Perhaps you can take it from here.

Comment: Thanks Is this is true for all polynomials $f$? So how do I find the residues?

Comment: It's more generally true for all holomorphic functions, @user108605.

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't know how you know that $f'(z)$ is non-zero at the roots of $f$. Also, given I don't know the poles, how do I find the residues? Thanks

Comment: @user108605 We don't know that fact because it isn't true for roots with multiplicity greater than $1$. However, you do not need that. Going through the details of prooving the simplicity of the poles should give you a very useful representation of $f'$ in terms of $g$, which will make the limit easy to evaluate.

Comment: @user108605 $f'(z)$ need not be non-zero in the zeros of $f$. But if $f \not\equiv 0$ on all components of its domain, and $f(z_0) = 0$, then there is an $m\in \mathbb{N}\setminus \{0\}$ and a holomorphic $g$ with $g(z_0) \neq 0$ such that $f(z) = (z-z_0)^m\cdot g(z)$.

Comment: @G.H.Faust sorry I really don't get what to do

Comment: @user108605 I have made an edit that should get you somewhere.

Comment: @G.H.Faust Is this the argument principle http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArgumentPrinciple.html? What are the poles of a polynomial?

Comment: @DanielFischer So basically its $10{\pi}i$?

Comment: @user108605 After the reasoning already in my answer above, the only theorem I really use is residue theorem. So if you're asking whether I'm using that result, the answer is no. But I do suspect my reasoning would generalise to proove that result. A polynomial does not have poles - If this question is motivated by the page you link to, then note that the page is talking about a wider class of functions.

Comment: @G.H.Faust Is my answer right?

Comment: @user108605 Five zeros, counting multiplicity, hence $2\pi i \cdot 5$.

Comment: @user108605 Yes, but prooving it should be what convinces you of that.